# How to make a groovy script list files from a git repo?

Tags: github, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, gitlab

I need to write a groovy script that talks to git, go to a repository, get the list of file names, store it in an array and return. Then I'll show that in a Jenkins choice parameter.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Sure. That's possible. But please ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to use pipeline it will be easier. 
You can use following to get files from a directory recursively:

```
import groovy.io.FileType

def fileList = []

def dir = new File("your_repo_dir")
dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file ->
  fileList << file
}
```

And then in job properties you need to add choice param:

```
choiceParam(name: 'Repo Files', choices: fileList.join("\n"), description: '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use activeChoiceReactiveParam with public Git repository:

```
parameters {
    stringParam {
        name('BRANCH_NAME')
        defaultValue('master')
        description('git branche name')
        trim(true)
    }
    activeChoiceReactiveParam('PLAYBOOK') {
        description('Select a playbook')
        filterable()
        choiceType('SINGLE_SELECT')
        groovyScript {
            script("""
                |def fileList = ['/bin/bash', '-c', "git clone --single-branch --branch " + BRANCH_NAME + " https://git.repository.com/scm/project/repo.git > /dev/null 2>&1 ; cd repo ; git ls-tree -r origin/" + BRANCH_NAME + " --name-only"].execute()
                |fileList.waitFor()
                |return ["playbook-default.yml"] + fileList.text.readLines().findAll { it.startsWith("playbook").endsWith(".yml") }
                """.stripMargin())
            fallbackScript('return ["playbook-default.yml"]')
        }
        referencedParameter('BRANCH_NAME')
    }
```

Note: for now, I didn't manage to use credentials (event with SSH). I could be a good improvement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get list of branch from HTTPS GIT URL + Jenkins credential, use this activeChoiceReactiveParam:

```
activeChoiceReactiveParam('BRANCH_NAME') {
        description('Branch from git repo')
        filterable()
        choiceType('SINGLE_SELECT')
        groovyScript {
            script("""
                |credentialsId = '<TO-REPLACE-WITH-YOUR-CREDENTIAL-ID'
                |def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardUsernamePasswordCredentials.class, jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance, null, null ).find{it.id == credentialsId}
                |def url = 'https://' + creds.username + ':' + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(creds.password.getPlainText()) + '@bitbucket.url.com/scm/project/repo.git'
                |def fileList = ['/bin/bash', '-c', 'rm -rf branch-name > /dev/null 2>&1 ; git clone ' + url + ' branch-name > /dev/null 2>&1 ; cd branch-name ; git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" --sort -committerdate | sed "s|refs/[a-z]*/||g" | sed "s|origin/||g" '].execute()
                |fileList.waitFor()
                |return fileList.text.readLines()
                |""".stripMargin())
            fallbackScript('return ["branch-name-not-found"]')
        }
    }
```